# Which versions of the Entity Framework support compiled queries?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have seen it mentioned several times that you should use compiled queries with Entity Framework, because it increases efficiency, much in the same way that stored procedures being compiled and cached do in SQL Server.

Apparently, there are two versions of compiled queries, the first being `CompiledQuery`, which to my understanding only works with the `ObjectContext` and auto-compiled queries that work with both the `DbContext` and `ObjectContext`.

So in which versions of EF do compiled queries work and in what API context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 4.5 is the first version that supports automatic compilation and caching.  From the [Compiled Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx) documentation:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, LINQ queries are cached automatically. However, you can still use compiled LINQ queries to reduce this cost in later executions and compiled queries can be more efficient than LINQ queries that are automatically cached. Note that LINQ to Entities queries that apply the Enumerable.Contains operator to in-memory collections are not automatically cached. Also parameterizing in-memory collections in compiled LINQ queries is not allowed.

The [`CompiledQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.compiledquery%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) support for manually compiled queries has existing since .NET 3.5 sp1.

Comment: Okay, I got it, but is there a chart that cross references the versions of EF to these LINQ capabilities. For instance EF 4.1 Code First was not a major release and I would assume tied to the same .NET Framework version as EF 4.0, right? But does EF 4.1 have different support for compiled queries, being as this was the first version of a different modeling methodology?

Comment: thanks, that is more along the lines of what I am looking for, appreciated. Sorry if my question was vague or confusing.